# How do I plot a parametric function?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I want to plot this parametric function:

$\qquad x=2\,\cos(\sqrt{12}t- π/3),\,y=4/\sqrt3 \sin(\sqrt{12}t- π/3)$

where $t$ goes from 0 to 8

I tried to make a plot, but I didn't know how because it's my first time using Mathematica.

Comment: Have you seen `ParametricPlot[]`?

Comment: yes, I tried it but I don't get the result

Comment: The first few examples look like the kind of formulas you're trying to plot.  Pay close attention to the capitalization, commas, braces, square brackets for functions instead of parentheses, .  I cannot tell from your description what you did wrong.

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{2 Cos[Sqrt[12] t - Pi/3], 4/Sqrt[3] Sin[Sqrt[12] t - Pi/3]}, {t, 0, 8}]` works fine. If that is not what you want, then you would want a more explicit explanation in your question.

Comment: this is exactly what I want,
thank you all

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = {2 Cos[Sqrt[12] t - π/3], 4 Sqrt[3] Sin[Sqrt[12] t - π/3]}

(* {2 Sin[π/6 + 2 Sqrt[3] t], -4 Sqrt[3] Cos[π/6 + 2 Sqrt[3] t]} *)
```

The expressions are periodic with period `π/Sqrt[3]`

```
Solve[expr == (expr /. t -> t + x) && 0 < x < π, x]

(* {{x -> π/Sqrt[3]}} *)

expr == (expr /. t -> t + π/Sqrt[3]) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Plotting the separate expressions

```
Plot[expr, {t, 0, 8}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

The [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) overlays itself after every `π/Sqrt[3]`

```
Legended[
 ParametricPlot[expr, {t, 0, π/Sqrt[3]},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, ColorData["Rainbow"][t]]],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, π/Sqrt[3]}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Also `FunctionPeriod[expr, t]` can be used.